# How can I Delete Cell in AQGridView?

Tags: iphone, gridview, uicollectionview, aqgridview

I am using [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView) to show images in GridView. Now i have to Delete The Cell which is added in GridView. In table View We can delete Each Cell using`commitEditingStyle` is there any Method In AQGridView Framework. Or Please give me any Alternate Framework for Insert and Delete Which is showing in GridView.

My another Question is If i use `UIColletionView` it will Support in below iOS 6 or Not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[gridArray removeObjectAtIndex:[albumCell displayIndex]];
NSIndexSet* set = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[albumCell displayIndex]]; 
[gridView beginUpdates];    
[gridView deleteItemsAtIndices:set  withAnimation:AQGridViewItemAnimationFade];
[gridView endUpdates];
```

[also check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320920/how-to-enable-aqgridview-edit-mode)

Comment: where i can add this Method

Comment: i post link see this link it same as your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

[GMGridView](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/gmgridview) is an alternative gridview framework for AQGridView

If you want to achieve delete with AQGridView, you can create a custom cell.
Add button to this cell to delete
Add delegate method in AQGridViewDelegate which should be implemented in your class.